# Removing doubles while iterating a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

I'm trying to remove doubles from a dataframe.

Basically, the dataframe contains two (or more) occurence of a document.
The doubles can be found by comparing the description of the document. 
In my logic, I had to find who the duplicates are, copy the data and drop them from both the dataframe and the iterated dataframe.

But it appears there are still doubles, I do think it is because of the drop but don't know how to fix it.
[image: Dataset screen]
So what is in green is the description, I need to drop one of the two, and fuse all that there is in black.

For example:

URL1 + URL2|Explorimmo + Bien_ici|Apartment|Description

Unfortunately, I can't link the dataset.

```
file = pd.ExcelFile(mc.file_path)
df = pd.read_excel(file)

description_duplicate = df.loc[df.duplicated(['DESCRIPTION']) == True]

for idx1, clean in description_duplicate.iterrows():
    for idx2, dirty in description_duplicate.iterrows():
        if idx1 != idx2:
            if clean['DESCRIPTION'] == dirty['DESCRIPTION']:
                clean['CRAWL_SOURCE'] = clean['CRAWL_SOURCE'] + " / " +dirty['CRAWL_SOURCE']
                clean['URL'] = clean['URL'] + " / " + dirty['URL']
                description_duplicate = description_duplicate.drop(idx2)
                df = df.drop(idx2)
                df[idx1] = clean
```

Comment: This would be easier to answer with a [mcve]

Comment: If it is not only the `DESCRIPTION` field which you need to compare to check if it is a duplicate, this might help: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html

Comment: What other field should I check? A lot of the fields are "size" "price" "stairs" so I chose to only compare on "description" and "images" as they are the one that gives the more "uniqueness", is this thinking wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to remove duplicates with the `pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates()` function:

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset='DESCRIPTION', inplace=True)
```

Comment: You can extend the subset and give a list of columns `['col_x', 'col_y']`, if the `DESCRIPTION` field is not sufficient

Comment: But I'm losing the information of where the duplicates comes from if I do that. 
Does the drop_duplicates function keeps one unique document? I can't find that in the pandas doc.

Comment: Yes, it will keep the first record by default. You can even specify, if you want to keep the first, the last or none of the records. See the documentation here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html

Comment: And if you do not want to loose the information, of where the duplicate origins from, just set `inplace=False` and assign the result to a new dataframe.